# Нужен совет, как лучше сделать страницу c графиками

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, canvas, диаграммы

Есть такой [макет](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eqRd.jpg)

Рассчитан он на мобильные устройства. Делается на HTML5.

Не могу понять как лучше сделать данный экран. Просто сделать, конечно легко, но есть пару нюансов:

1. Данный экран можно  **масштабировать**. Масштабирование не произвольное, есть 4 уровня детализации:

   - полный временной отрезок;
   - годы (4-5 помещаются на экран);
   - месяцы;
   - дни.
2. Его можно **скролить**. Влево вправо вверх вниз.
3. Внутри есть **кликабельные элемены**. Можно нажать на часть линии и провалиться в соответствующий временной промежуток (просто на другую страницу).
4. Вдоль линии выстраивается **график**, на основе имеющихся данных. Также он должен ложиться точно в соответствии датами.
5. Масштабирование должно происходить **анимировано**.

Не могу сообразить для каких частей интерфейса, какие технологии использовать. Чтоб результат максимально соответствовал макету и не упирался в производительность, при наличии большого объема данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите библиотеку для графиков, коих множество. из не бесплатных могу посоветовать highcharts

Comment: Выложите картинку в посте.

Comment: из d3.js можно подобное собрать